# Insert into one table to another and use case in select

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have a query :

```
insert into xx_tab_abc
(wr_flag,actual_term_date,person_num)

SELECT BOL_FLAG, ACTUAL_TERM_DATE, PERSON_NUMBER FROM WR_TAB
```

Can i modify this select query in such a way that if `actual_term_date in wr_tab` is not null then 'Y' is inserted into `wr_flag` else no value is passed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT case when ACTUAL_TERM_DATE is not null 
            then 'y' 
            else BOL_FLAG
       end, 
       ACTUAL_TERM_DATE, PERSON_NUMBER 
FROM WR_TAB
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you don't want to insert anything if `ACTUAL_TERM_DATE` is null?  If so, you can just do this

```
insert into xx_tab_abc (wr_flag,
                        actual_term_date,
                        person_num
                       )

SELECT 'Y', 
       ACTUAL_TERM_DATE, 
       PERSON_NUMBER 
FROM WR_TAB
WHERE ACTUAL_TERM_DATE IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into xx_tab_abc
(wr_flag,actual_term_date,person_num)
SELECT decode(NVL(ACTUAL_TERM_DATE,' '),ACTUAL_TERM_DATE,'Y',NULL), ACTUAL_TERM_DATE, PERSON_NUMBER FROM WR_TAB
```